# Blender hair simulation fine in viewport, but half of it won't render

Tags: rendering, particles, eevee-render-engine, hair

I have been creating a 3D character which uses hair simulation. It works fine in the viewport, but when I go to render it, half of it has disappeared. It does work in cycles, but that won't be an option as it takes around 8 minutes to render each frame.

Here is what it looks like in the viewport:

[image: viewport]

And here is what it looks like rendered (with eevee):

[image: rendered]

**Q:** How to get the preview settings for the actual rendering?

Comment: please do not edit your question to add [solved] to the title. You may accept your own answer, the community will see that it is "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others having the same problem: I found that it worked to just use the same settings in a different particle system. I'm not sure what actually happened, but I'm just glad that it works!